# Can someone explain how the dilation in the ConvolutionalLayer works?

Tags: neural-networks

ConvolutionalLayer has a few optional parameters. "Dilation" is one I'm having trouble understanding how it works and the documentation is terse.

Can anyone give some explanation?

**References:**

- https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/convolution.md#nn.SpatialDilatedConvolution
- http://vladlen.info/papers/dilated-convolutions.pdf

Comment: I found [this explaination](http://www.inference.vc/dilated-convolutions-and-kronecker-factorisation/) useful

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation will improve, hopefully with a picture.

In English terms, dilation 'stretches' the area over which the kernel is convolved, by subsampling the original data (sampling it every d+1 pixels).

In the meantime, here's something that lets you visualize the receptive field (the effective kernel) of a given kernelsize and dilation. Black pixels represent pixels that participate in the convolution, white pixels are ones that are skipped:

```
plotReceptiveField[kernel_, dilation_] := Module[
    {d = dilation+1},
    ArrayPlot[
        Drop[Array[
            If[Total[Mod[{##},d]] == 0, 1, 0]&, 
            kernel*d
        ], Sequence @@ dilation],
        Mesh -> True, ImageSize -> Small
    ]
]
```

Here are some pictures:

```
plotReceptiveField[{3, 3}, {0, 0}] (* no dilation *)
```

[image]

```
plotReceptiveField[{3, 3}, {1, 1}] (* uniform dilation of 1 *)
```

[image]

```
plotReceptiveField[{3, 3}, {2, 0}] (* non-uniform dilation *)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, and is the improved documentation expected in v11.0.1 or v11.1?

Comment: 11.0.1 ship sailed long ago. It'll have to be for 11.1 or 11.2 if we run out of time (I'm sure you'd rather prefer working recurrent networks than slightly improved documentation).